# Find word with conditions in file

Tags: regex, shell

I want to find a text from a file which is starting from "i-" but its not working.

```
egrep '^i-*' temp
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Then fix it.  If you want *help* with doing that, you'll have to provide some more details.  (And what does this have to do with nsregularexpression?)

Comment: Provide a sample of `temp` file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are talking about:

```
egrep '^i-.*' temp
```